# WXPython, passing variable from left to right panel

Tags: python, attributes, wxpython, definition

I am writing a program to play a video on the right panel when a button pressed on a left panel after selecting what to play. This acts as a test function to show the user. I am a beginner in using Python and WXPython. Learning on the go.
I have added a snippet of the code that I am stuck on below:

```
import wx, wx.media
filePathList = ["None", "None", "None", "None", "None"]

class FrameClass (wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      super(FrameClass, self).__init__(None, title = "Super Bot", size = (750, 400))

      vsplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
      left = LeftPanel(vsplitter, self)
      self.right = RightPanel(vsplitter, self)
      vsplitter.SplitVertically(left, self.right)
      vsplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)
      self.Show(True)

class LeftPanel (wx.Panel):
   def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
     wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)
     testBtn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Test", pos = (5, 20))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed1, testBtn1)

   def buttonPressed1(self, event):
     file0 = filePathList[0]
     self.right.onTestClick(file0)


class RightPanel (wx.Panel):
   def __init__(self, parent, media):
     wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)
     self.mediaFilePath = media

   def onTestClick(self):
     self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, size = (500, 300), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend = wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)
     self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
     self.testMedia.Load(self.mediaFilePath)

   def play(self, event):
     self.testMedia.Play()
```

Currently all works well. What apart from passing the video to the rightPanel video onTestClick. Where is shows the current error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "frame1.py", line 151, in buttonPressed1
 self.right.onTestClick(file0)
 AttributeError: 'LeftPanel' object has no attribute 'right'
```

I can imagine that because right is defined in the FrameClass that it is not known about inside of the LeftPanel when trying to use it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could eschew creating the panels as seperate classes and eliminate the splitter at the same time. Just declare the panels as `self.left_panel` and `self.right_panel` then use a sizer to organise them. Object oriented programming is not always the answer, as in, when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Thank you for your inputs as well. Most helpful.
I just needed to make the left panel aware of the right panel. In this case...

```
    vsplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
    right = RightPanel(vsplitter, self)
    left = LeftPanel(vsplitter, right)
    vsplitter.SplitVertically(left, right)
    vsplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

    self.Show(True)



class LeftPanel (wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, top):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)

    self.refTop = top
```

and when I wanted to send it something, I reference "self.refTop". Such as...

```
def buttonPressed1(self, event):
    file1 = filePathList[0]
    self.refTop.onTestClick(file1)
```

making sure that RightPanel has an argument ready for it.

```
class RightPanel (wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, media):
        self.mediaFilePath = media
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix, you can just call:

```
self.GetParent().right.onTestClick(file0)
```

which is kind-of ugly, because the the parent creates children
and children must know about the structure of the parent at
the same time.

Probably the most wxPython-ish solution would be to create your
own event, which would be created and triggered when the button
is pressed. This event would be handled in the FrameClass.
There is a nice intro here:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html#custom-event-summary